# Python PyqT6 QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, database, model-view-controller, pyqt6, qsqltablemodel

I trying to build my QSTableModel. I need display data from DB along with checkbox in every cell.

Here is my code

```
class MyModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, db=QSqlDatabase()):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent, db)
        
    def columnCount(self, index):
        count = QSqlTableModel.columnCount(self, index)
        print("column count - ", QSqlTableModel.columnCount(self, index))
        return count
    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        print("row count - ", QSqlTableModel.rowCount(self))
        return QSqlTableModel.rowCount(self)
    

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if row == 0 and col == 0:
                return "<--left"
            if row == 1 and col == 1:
                return "right-->"
            return "SOMETHING"
```

This `IF` gives me checkboxes in every cell.

```
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            return Qt.CheckState.Checked
```

If I tell what to display something explicitly in the cell its working OK. But I want to display data from database. What should replace "SOMETHING" ?

Comment: The last line of the method should be `return super().data(index, role)` (with single indent).

Comment: @BennyLutin You're *overriding* a function, *altering* its expected behavior, which means that you must be aware of 2 aspects: 1. when the function is called, it's expected to do something closely related to what called it expects; 2. that "what called it" may also need a return value that should reflect what expected. Whenever you want to *override* something for some reason, but still follow the *default behavior* for the others, that means that you **must** do and eventually return the expected default result in those cases. That's the scope of a final `[return ]super().<function>(<args>)`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. and full explanation